# Learning french from beginning to end

Tags: grammaire

For four years I've been in "intergrated french" and I'm still finding French quite difficult (especially grammar).  I know I can learn other lanaguages because I know may programming languages.

I'm determined to learn it and I was wondering if there was any good books available to help me learn the language or really-well published online articles.

Comment: Natural languages are very different from programming languages.

Comment: There's no magic bullet. You can't learn a language in a day or even in a year. After four years, you aren't after learning material: read real books and articles in French, on any topic that interest you.

Comment: 1) Read. 2) Listen. 3) Repeat 1 and 2 over and over again with consistency for at least 3-5 years, that is, if you don't have the option to move to a French speaking region. If you are a competent writer in your primary language, then you are unlikely to become a bad one in French. Writing comes naturally with reading comprehension and speaking comes naturally with listening comprehension. That's how I learnt French by myself from scratch.

Answer (score 7):

The best way to learn and speak fluent French (and any other language by the way) is immersion: go and live in a country where people speak French for at least 3 months, you will learn the stuff that isn't taught in classrooms.

This is useless if you go to a place where you can find many people who speak your language. I have a friend who went to London to learn English. He came back with the same level of English than before, just because he spent every evening with French people.

Comment: This sounds like a good idea but I can't afford moving to a country for 3 months.  +1, though.